# Python 3 filter list of ordered dict items by a specific key value

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I am iterating a list of other list variables to an ordered dictionary variable and appending them to a new list variable. I am trying to filter the new ordered dict entries to only get the results where variable 8 in the list is equal to "C". The code I have below is giving me a value error though.

```
    keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6', 'key7', 'key8']
    blank_list = []
    for a in list(zip(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
        orglist = OrderedDict(zip(keys, a))
        orglist2 = {a: b for a, b in orglist if b[8] == 'C'}
        blank_list.append(orglist2)
```

How can I fix this to only retrieve ordereddict values where var8 is equal to a specific value ('C')? The result should be a list of ordered dict objects where the var8 is equal to 'C' regardless of what the other variables equal. Other potential values for var8 could be blank or none.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what var1-8 would be? And an example of the output would he helpful as well

Comment: What it should do if b[8] is not 'C'?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ... When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mcve].

Comment: I am working on editing my question with more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your approach, this should fix it:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6', 'key7', 'key8']
blank_list = []
for a in zip(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
    orglist = OrderedDict(zip(keys, a))
    orglist2 = {a: b for a, b in orglist.items() if b[6] == 'C'}
    blank_list.append(orglist2)
```

Your issue was, that `for a, b in orglist` wouldn't work, because iterating through a dictionary only gives you the dictionary keys.

but maybe this would be bit more readable:

```
for a in zip(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
    if a[6] == 'C':
        blank_list.append(dict(zip(keys, a)))
```

or

```
for a in zip(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
    orglist = OrderedDict(zip(keys, a))
    if orglist['key7'] == 'C':
        blank_list.append(orglist)
```